# Linking content from one page to another in Confluence

Tags: confluence

We have bunch of Confluence pages for each team to note down the leaves. Each such page consists of a table with team, team member name, month, week ..etc.

Now we want to have a consolidate page which shows information about all the teams in a single page. Can we create a consolidated page which uses the content in all other pages?

I read about macros but couldn't understand how they can be used. Is it possible to use content from one page in another page dynamically?

Comment: We use for this the "include Page" macro. Look at here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Include+Page+Macro

Comment: I'd just add that you could also use the Excerpt Include macro, which is basically the same as the Include Page macro except it doens't have to include ALL of the content from another page. @user3415653 do you want to make an answer?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can by using the "Excerpt" macro (to mark one section in a page as "insertable" and use this in another page). If you need to have multiple sections in one page to reuse in other pages, there is also a "Multi Excerpt" macro.

So, for example, if you have a page with a few lines of text, you can basically insert the excerpt macro and paste all content into it that you want to reuse on other pages:

[image: Excerpt]
<sub>(source: [imagestack.net](https://imagestack.net/i/423f7b3359b6.jpg))</sub>

(in this case I want to reuse "line 2")

In another page, you can reference this marked content by inserting the "Excerpt Include" macro and specifying the page you want to take the marked content from:

[image: Excerpt]
<sub>(source: [imagestack.net](https://imagestack.net/i/14fef95fbbac.jpg))</sub>

The result in this case is

[image: Excerpt]